# EXIF does not return orienation details with PHP

Tags: php, exif, uiimageorientation

I am trying to get image orientation details using PHP exif_read_data() Function but unfortunately I am unable to get the desired details. I am getting only

```
Array
(
    [FILE] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => sasfasdfasd-asdf-asdasdf-afdsd-767563900.jpg
            [FileDateTime] => 1541527956
            [FileSize] => 302871
            [FileType] => 2
            [MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
        )

    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1000" height="750"
            [Height] => 750
            [Width] => 1000
            [IsColor] => 1
        )

    [COMMENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 100

        )

)
```

I am using PHP 7.2
Can someone please tell me how can I get Image orientation details using PHP?
I have checked my GD libraries as well as EXIF using PHP info. They are working fine.

Comment: What specifically do you want to get? And could you provide the code of how you get this array?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ice76. I am trying to rotate images taken from an Android phone's Camera. I need Image orientation details to do that. `<?php
    $input = 'C://xampp/htdocs/test.jpg';
    $exif = exif_read_data($input);    
    print_r($exif);
?>` This is the simple code, I was trying. Test.png is an image taken from an android phone.

Comment: MY bad. I got an answer. The image that I was using was after PHP uploading process. The image was changed and because of that I was not able to get all orientation details. I got the original image from a phone by an email and got desired details when tried to process it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out/!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the image you have created is done using LibGD, which by default does not write any extended EXIF data.

As the maintainer of the EXIF Extension that comes with PHP, I can give you a little inside of how this works under the hood:

When you load in an image using `exif_read_data()`, then by default the above sections are returned (with the exception of `COMMENT` in your case; as it is generated by LibGD). If a `MAKERNOTE` section is found within the binary meta data of the image, then PHP will attempt to resolve the value to one of the known formats to PHP[1].

If a signature is then matched with one of the known formats, then PHP will read all the relevant IFD (Image File Data) data from the header and attempt to resolve some of the tag names according to a baked in list of tags. This makes the returned array much more reliant to work with, instead of having to write code like `echo $exif['0x0112'];` (Orientation), the array becomes something like: `echo $exif['Orientation'];`.

If a signature however is not matched, then PHP will still attempt to read the relevant EXIF data within an image, however tags will not be mapped for non standard tags. PHP will also continue to read things like thumbnail data etc, given the binary data is following the EXIF specification.

Finally; PHP's EXIF extension is read-only, so even if you were to know your orientation from the image in question, you can't manually write it with the default extension that comes with PHP I'm afraid.

[1] http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/exif/exif.c;h=d37a61f83da7bd8c14eeaa0d14762e3a4e7c80e6;hb=HEAD#l1336